# how to test whether one list is a member of another

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, membership

Lets say I have two lists, `((1 2 3))` and `(((1 2 3)) ((4 5)))`. I want to be able to tell if the first list is a member of the second list.  I have tried to use `subsetp`, but it does not return true for this query. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: How would the first list be a subset of the second list???

Comment: Because the first element of the second list is equal to the first list.

Comment: That's not what a subset is. That's *membership*. The first list is a member of the second list, but not a subset.

Comment: I apologize for the incorrect wording. How would I solve the membership problem then?

Comment: `member` checks if _an given element_ is a top-level element of a list. `subsetp` checks if _every element_ of list-1 is a top-level element of list-2. If you want to check membership, maybe that's want you want: `(member '((1 2 3)) '(((1 2 3)) ((4 5))) :test #'tree-equal)`

Answer (score 6):

As Rainer Joswig [mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19612193/common-lisp-advanced-subset/19636292#comment29114156_19612193), you're not checking for subsets, but for members, which you can do using the aptly named [`member`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mem_m.htm) function.  `Member` returns a generalized boolean, i.e., `nil` for false, and something, not necessarily `t`, non-`nil` for true.  Specifically, if an element is a member of the list, `member` returns the tail of the list whose first element is the element.

```
CL-USER> (member 3 '(1 2 3 4 5))
(3 4 5)
CL-USER> (member 7 '(1 2 3 4 5))
NIL
```

Of course, when checking membership in a list, there's a question of how to compare the given item with the elements of the list.  `Member`'s default comparison is `eql`, which works on things like numbers, as shown in the example above.  For your case, however, you probably want to test with `equal`, since `((1 2 3))` might not be the *same* object as the first element of `(((1 2 3)) ((4 5)))`:

```
CL-USER> (member '((1 2 3)) '(((1 2 3)) ((4 5))))
NIL
CL-USER> (member '((1 2 3)) '(((1 2 3)) ((4 5))) :test 'equal)
(((1 2 3)) ((4 5)))
CL-USER> (member '((4 5)) '(((1 2 3)) ((4 5))) :test 'equal)
(((4 5)))
CL-USER> (member '((1 2 4)) '(((1 2 3)) ((4 5))) :test 'equal)
NIL
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have lists as elements of your sets for `subsetp`, you have to change the value of the `:test` keyword.

```
CL-USER 1 > (subsetp '(1 2 3) '(1 2 3 4 5))
T
CL-USER 2 > (subsetp '((1) (2) (3)) '((1) (2) (3) (4) (5)))
NIL
```

The first one gives T, the second one gives NIL. Why? Because equality is checked with `#'eql` which works for identical objects or numbers of the same value and of same type. Since two lists must not be identical objects, `(eql '(1) '(1))` gives NIL. (That may depend on your CL implementation.) If you want to compare a tree of conses, `tree-equal` can help you.

```
CL-USER 3 > (subsetp '((1) (2) (3)) '((1) (2) (3) (4) (5)) :test #'tree-equal)
T
```

I don't understand the structure of the sets you gave as example completely, but I hope this helps.