# In Common Lisp how do I search for a sublist within a list

Tags: common-lisp

If I want to find whether (x 2) exists within a list containing ((x 2) (y 2) (z 2)) for example, how do I do this?

```
(member '(x 2) '((x 2) (y 2) (z 2)))
```

returns NIL as does find

Thanks for the help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Test if array is inside a list in lisp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19287777/test-if-array-is-inside-a-list-in-lisp)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to test whether one list is a member of another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19612193/how-to-test-whether-one-list-is-a-member-of-another)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
? (member '(x 2) '((x 2) (y 2) (z 2)) :test 'equal)
((X 2) (Y 2) (Z 2))
```

In Common Lisp, `member` uses `eql` as the default test, which does not work in this case.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547436/whats-the-difference-between-eq-eql-equal-and-equalp-in-common-lisp) for details regarding `eq`, `eql`, `equal` and `equalp`.

Comment: @mbratch `eql`, actually. What is `equ`?

Comment: Hehe oops, I meant `eql`. My bad. I'm bouncing betwixt too many different languages... ;)