# Why does member function return nil

Tags: lisp

I have a list:

```
*DSTATES* = ( ( list1 ) ( list2 ) ( list3 ) ... ( listn )  )
```

And a list of state names, `x = ( list )`

`*DSTATES*` has `( (zero) (three two one) (two) (three zero) )`

x has `(two)`.

Here's my code:

```
(map '() #'(lambda (x)
           (princ "Looking at transition ") (princ x)
           (princ #\newline)
           (if (and (eq '() (member x *DSTATES*)) (not (eq '() x)))
               (progn
                 (princ x) (princ " is not a member of *DSTATES*")
                 (princ #\newline)
                 (setq *DSTATES* (append *DSTATES* (list x)))))
           (princ "Intermediate *DSTATES* ") (princ *DSTATES*)
           (princ #\newline) (princ #\newline))
       trans)
```

When I do `( eq '() ( member x *DSTATES* ) )` it always--as far as I can tell--returns true. Because of this `*DSTATES*` gets larger and larger and my loop, which has a stop condition on the size of `*DSTATES*` never terminates.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Style problem 1: never append to the end of a list.

Comment: Style problem 2: `(eq '() foo)` is `(null foo)`. If it is a boolean use `(not foo)`.

Comment: Ok thanks for those tips. What's wrong with appending to the end of a list?

Comment: Style problem 3: instead of `if` and `progn` use `when`.

Comment: lists are linked cons cells. adding to the front is fast. Adding to the end needs to traverse the whole list.

Comment: problem 4: `*states*` is a list of lists. `member` will not find anything, since it does not look at the sublists.

Comment: Right ok, thanks for that. For this problem, performance isn't a huge issue, but i'm glad you pointed that out

Comment: never do that. It's just wrong. Don't write bad code.

Comment: alright then, noted. So when I apply (member) to a list of lists what does it see if it doesn't see the sublists?

Comment: `member` checks if an item is in a list. `member` does not check if an item is in a sublist.

Comment: Ok, I need `member` to see `(two)` as a list item and not a sublist. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I would iterate over the list and see if the item is a member of one of the sublists...

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was able to solve it using `#'tree-equal` in the `:test` section of `member`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do `(member x *DSTATES* :test #'tree-equal)`

That will make `member` check membership.

Hope that helps guys

[how to test whether one list is a member of another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19612193/how-to-test-whether-one-list-is-a-member-of-another)